# Should $x=-2$ be included as an answer for $\frac{x^2+8x+12}{x^2+5x+6}>0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, wolfram-alpha

$$\frac{x^2+8x+12}{x^2+5x+6}>0$$
First of all while solving inequalities I need to check domain so in this case $$x^2+5x+6\neq0$$
$$x\neq-2,\ x\neq-3$$ 
Later on
$$\frac{(x+6)(x+2)}{(x+3)(x+2)}>0$$
Then get critical values draw number line and get
$$x\in(-\infty;-6)\cup(-3;-2)\cup(-2;+\infty)$$
However according to [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%5E2%2b8x%2b12%29/%28x%5E2%2b5x%2b6%29%3E0%20find%20x) $x=-2$ is included as an answer.

> *So am I wrong or wolframalpha is wrong?*

Also I checked $\frac{x}{x}=1$ and [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x/x=1%20find%20x) also includes $x=0$ but once again I think it's incorrect?

Comment: Well, there is a removable singularity at $x=-2$.

Comment: Try solving $x/x > 0$ with Wolfram. However, $1/x > 0$ produces the correct answer.

Comment: I am inclined to agree with Wolfram Alpha. Your expression "really wants" to be $\frac{x+6}{x+3}$, and perhaps assumed its more convoluted form by accident. With trigonometric identities, one tends to take this poin of view. For example, there is a standard identity that expresses $\sum_{k=1}^n \cos k\theta$ as a fraction with $\sin(\theta/2)$ in the denominator. The identity is technically incorrect when $\sin(\theta/2)=0$, but it is standard not to worry about it.

Comment: @copper.hat ok so it's that way probably because wolfram simplifies expression at the beginning, but why it does so, if it's not always correct? why it doesnt check for a domain first?

Comment: I am a little surprised that Wolfram doesn't indicate that it has removed the removable singularities first.

Comment: You are right and Wolfram alpha is wrong.  Plugging $-2$ in place of $x$ on the left side of the given inequality does not yield a value $>0$ (because it doesn't yield a value at all), so $-2$ is not a solution.  Solving an inequality does not mean solving what you get by removing singularities (or, in simpler language, cancelling troublesome factors); it means solving the actual inequality that was given.

Answer (score 7):

As it seems you are simply solving an inequality, and entered it as such, you are correct: the expression is not defined at $-2$.

Why Wolfram Alpha omitted $\,-3\,$ from the solutions, but included $\,-2\,$, seems inconsistent to me, as you note! It seems that if Wolfram is going to at least *be consistent*...either both values should be omitted, or both included.

Answer (score 4):

Wolfram alpha probably simplified the expression before it calculated the solutions.  You are right.  It is worth mentioning, however, that there is a hole at $x=-2$, and the limit as $x\rightarrow -2$ satisfies the inequality.

Comment: so is it a bug? can't believe noone noticed it for such long time

Comment: Yeah, I guess it must be.  Perhaps alpha is programmed to include limit points in its solution sets automatically - your $x/x$ example suggests the latter.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber This is probably not the explanation. Try solving $1/x^2>0$.

Comment: @Templar: *can't believe noone noticed it for such long time*... An awful lot of people did notice it, and many other features of W|A, for a very long time. In fact these are quite well known. The trouble begins when people consider W|A as something it is not.

Answer (score 4):

The function as written is certainly not defined at $x= -2,$ but it does have a removable singularity there. The only way to extend the definition (note the word extend) of the function so that it becomes continuous at $x = -2$ is to define the value at $-2$ to be $4$. Then the new function is identically equal to $\frac{x+6}{x+3}$ except at $x = -3,$ where it is not defined (and worse, the singularity at $x = -3$ is not removable).

Answer (score 1):

No, your expression is undefined at $x = -2$.  Are you taking a limit from the left or right???

Comment: why wolframalpha gives -2 as an answer then?

Comment: It's kinda hairsplittery.   I think that the expression is undefined there. Wolfram is eliding the removable singularity. I think it's a matter of taste, but I say $x \not= -2$.

Comment: Wolfram is wrong, but justifiably so.

Comment: Wolfram is not perfectt.